How to Merge Text Files avoiding Redundancy
I have open two instances of notepad.exe on Win11 opening the same text file but differing in input, while still having similarities and common data.
Here is an example of what it looks like, as Hannu requested:



Req.
Req.




a1
a1


a2
b1


a3
a2


a4
b2


a5
a5



I want to now merge these two files into one.
Hope this is clear.
>> Original Screenshot <<
Without manual intervention (ie, editing by hand), how do I command my system to fix the issue.

"notepad" -> Windows assumed.
If you have Git-Bash, MSYS, cygwin, or WSL installed...
Open a bash shell and widen the window so that it allows upwards 200 character columns.
Also make both files available as e.g. a.txt and b.txt then do:
$ diff -y -W 200 a.txt b.txt | less

If all good gods are with you you will see the files beside each other with the differences notable.
(This works nicely if the differences are up to "moderate", it gets harder if you get past that)

Further reading, get acquainted with patch:
https://www.pair.com/support/kb/paircloud-diff-and-patch/

Hannu, read up on sdiff, which does the side-by-side thing pretty well. And then there's comm -3

Is that Windows'y software? Then it won't happen ;-)

Not Windows, no. You mentioned diff (and patch) so I thought you'd like to know about the other two commands

One possible way is to use notepad++ with Compare module. Open in one document first file, second file in second document. Then Plugins->Compare->Compare or Ctrl+Alt+C and you will see something like:

This tool is not exactly for automation, but will give you very visual image of compared lines.
